# how I can sign message using web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, ecrecover, authentication

I know that I can sign a message using web3js, but I don't know how I can do that, then how to verify that signature using ecrecover()?

Answer (score 1):

You can use metamask to sign transaction see their example

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/signing-data.html#sign-typed-data-v4

Basically the steps are,

```
const keep_it_hidden = process.env.Key; // this is a private key

const CHAINID = 1;
const hash_data =  web3.utils.soliditySha3(CHAINID, accounts[0] , "some data" ); // any data you want the func to hash
const sign = await web3.eth.accounts.sign(hash_data, keep_it_hidden )['signature'] // sign the hashed data
```

Now in the smart contract import the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA) operations from OpenZeppelin, you have `sign as signature` you can run using  e.g `recover` method and `toEthSignedMessageHash` for hash the message in the contract

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/6af4ed6169ee4165ce86457f98c0a568bd9d7491/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol#L99

I hope this is clear

Comment: where I can put a java script code

Comment: where I can put a java script code